# Где взять исходники загрузчика AVR109?

Tags: c, ассемблер, avr

Компания Atmel позаботилась о потребителях и выпустила исходники загрузчика AVR109. Но не ясно, где их найти.
Друзья, подскажите, где взять исходники bootloader-а AVR109. Перерыл весь интернет - нигде не могу их найти. На сайте avrfreaks.net какие либо ссылки на исходники не работают. Ссылки на сайт Atmel тоже не работают, т.к. его выкупил Microchip.

Есть у кого исходники загрузчика AVR109?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылка на исходники размещена на той же странице, что и описание самой технологии

[AVR109: Using Self Programming on tinyAVR and megaAVR devices](https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en591230)

Прямая ссылка: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/AVR109.zip

Answer (score 2):

Может эти вам подойдут, к сожелению сайт на китайском: http://www.pudn.com/Download/item/id/316318.html

Comment: Благодарю за содействие, но на этом сайте товарищи китайцы намудрили с доступом к ресурсам. Чтобы что-то скачать нужно регистрироваться плюс выкладывать 5 каких-то исходников или документов. Это можно сделать, но в другой раз. Ещё раз благодарю за содействие

Comment: Ответ ссылка — плохой ответ.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Так ответ выше идентичный моему :D

Comment: Вопрос был "где взять сорскод", там ответ "по ссылке". Все правильно.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/516268)

Comment: Во-во @AlexSazonov прав ;)

Comment: Вы рофлите чтоли? ответ выше полностью идентичен, просто больше подошел автору. Что самое главное указать? хедеры из загрузчика чтоли?

Comment: Ваша ссылка — на сомнительный ресурс на китайском. Ссылка выше — на нормальный сайт. Ответ выше дает _описание_ где взять т.е. не просто копипаст из урла в браузере. У вас же ничего подобного нет.

Comment: `ксожелению` пишется раздельно: "к сожалению". В общем поводов для минуса и для тревоги "Не является ответом" довольно много.

Comment: Успокойтесь, я просто хотел показать, что далеко не каждый ответ идеален ;) Извините, если обидел. Хорошего дня! ;)